# Auto join jitsi meet

Tags: javascript, html, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am using [Jitsi-Meet iframe Api](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-iframe) to have a custom video calling feature. It is working as expected. However I would like to add a feature to this. The feature is to auto-join or auto-start the meeting on http load. How do I do this instead of the user manually pressing the join button?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://meet.jit.si/external_api.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var domain = "meet.jit.si";
            var options = {
                roomName: "TestingMeet",
                width: "100%",
                height: 1080,
                parentNode: document.querySelector("#meet"),
                configOverwrite: {

                },
                interfaceConfigOverwrite: {
                    DEFAULT_BACKGROUND: "#3b98ff",
                    noSsl: true,
                    SHOW_JITSI_WATERMARK: false,
                    HIDE_DEEP_LINKING_LOGO: true,
                    SHOW_BRAND_WATERMARK: false,
                    SHOW_WATERMARK_FOR_GUESTS: false,
                    SHOW_POWERED_BY: false,
                    TOOLBAR_BUTTONS: [
                        'microphone', 'camera', 'closedcaptions', 'desktop', 'fullscreen',
                        'fodeviceselection', 'hangup', 'profile', 'recording',
                        'livestreaming', 'etherpad', 'sharedvideo', 'settings', 'raisehand',
                        'videoquality', 'filmstrip', 'feedback', 'stats', 'shortcuts',
                        'tileview'
                    ],
                }
            }
            var api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
            api.executeCommands({
                displayName: ['nickname'],
                toggleVideo: [],
                toggleAudio: []
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .title {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: "Segoe UI";
            font-size: 48px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="meet"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't... AutoPlay standards request that audiocontext is checked for in regards to user interaction without it videos/etc start paused.etc broke as hell.

Glad I can save you hours! Weeks even. For real though, don't overly bypass. You can build a positive score to slide right in no clicks but you'll need this "form" every now and then or indefinitely.

Comment: @blanknamefornow hey thanks alot for your reply. Thing is I have seen people integrating jitsi meet with auto-join meeting. So I know there is a way to do this. I understand about videos and audios but in this context, its a button which can be triggered.

Comment: prejoinPageEnabled: false

Comment: It's in your configuration files, a fast find. It should be commented out but they've added it for sure. Believe that's what you're looking for! :) https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/a582f1c191bc193e5c7e40de44fbce5a9ffbde3b/config.js#L416

Comment: Thanks I just saw it now. I posted it as the answer:)

Answer (score 6):

I got it, there is an option called as configOverwrite; and you have to add this inside:

```
var options = {
                roomName: "RoomName",
                width: "100%",
                height: 1080,
                parentNode: document.querySelector("#meet"),
                configOverwrite: {
                    prejoinPageEnabled: false //This here
                },
...
...
```

Comment: Sweet, I saw the config file, wasn't sure this could be passed. nice! :)

Comment: @blanknamefornow i still need to provide a name for the user. How can I do it inside the js script?

Comment: https://meet.jit.si/roomname#userInfo.displayName="username" I see in the API

Comment: Yup that'd do it, the box will show up blank tho, but it will pass.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, just pass #config.prejoinPageEnabled=false, in the url and done.

Answer (score 1):

Now you should pass:

```
configOverwrite: {
    prejoinConfig: {
        enabled: false
    }
}
```